# .Bat file to locate a specific file name and owner and move

Tags: batch-file

Pardon my ignorance on .bat files, but I'm not accustomed to them.
What I am trying to do is get a .bat file to search for a specific filename and then also perform a search of that .txt file to locate a specific owner of the file. If all matches, move that file off to another directory.

Is this possible and how do I even start?
I'm familiar with programming with JS but that's all.
Never created a batch file before but hear all the time they work wonders.

*****This is what i've gathered so far...and cannot get this to work. You will note also that i'm not sure how to tell it to search for a specific owner of the file...ie (Jane Doe) and File name of (Testing) and if all matches, move to another directory*****

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "source=C:\Users\andrew.moss\Desktop\Test1"
set "target=C:\Users\andrew.moss\Desktop\Test2"
set "searchString=Testing"

set "found="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /m /i /l /c:"%Testing%" "%C:\Users\andrew.moss\Desktop\Test1%" 2^>nul 
') do (
    if not defined found set "found=1"
    echo move "%%a" "%C:\Users\andrew.moss\Desktop\Test2%"
)

if not defined found (
    echo Failure
)

pause
```

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, so you should share your efforts. A good starting point is the [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command -- type `help dir` or `dir /?` into a new command prompt window and read the help very carefully...

Comment: When i run what i have so far, all i get is 'FAILURE'

Comment: You enclosed two file paths in `%%`, but these should be removed... To get the owner, you could parse the output of `dir /Q` by a `for /F` loop, but that might become a bit tricky... not sure whether there exists a method relying on `wmic`...

Comment: Ok i removed % surrounding the file paths but i am still getting 'Failure' when running the script

Comment: Ah, and `/c:"%Testing%"` should read `/c:"%searchString%"`...

Comment: Changed to /c:"%searchString%" and still when running it gives me 'failure'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127738/discussion-between-drew-and-aschipfl).

Comment: I want to thank you very much for providing that script and also taking time out of your day to put it together. 
I tried the script, and when running it, all i get is 'file not found' 
I have no clue what i am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I started from scratch to provide a script which I believe suits your requirements, so here it is:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=."       & rem // (path to directory where to search for files)
set "_TARGET=.."      & rem // (path to directory where to move found files)
set "_PATTERN=test.*" & rem // (file name pattern; may contain wild-cards)
set "$RECURSIVE=#"    & rem // (set to non-empty value to search sub-dir.s)
set "$OWNER=aschipfl" & rem /* (login name of owner; may be preceded with
                        rem     domain and a backslash, like `DOMAIN\`) */

rem // Predefine recursive option:
if defined $RECURSIVE set "$RECURSIVE=/S"
rem // Split domain off of owner:
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=\ eol=\ " %%C in ("%$OWNER%") do (
    if not "%%D"=="" (
        set "$DOMAIN=%%C"
        set "$OWNER=%%D"
    ) else set "$DOMAIN="
)

rem /* Loop through all matching files in the given location found by `dir`;
rem    the `/Q` option lets include domain/owner in the output; `findstr`
rem    filters out lines beginning with ` `, hence headers and footers: */
pushd "%_SOURCE%" || exit /B 1
for /F "tokens=4,*" %%E in ('
    dir /Q /N /-C %$RECURSIVE% /A:-D "%_PATTERN%" ^
        ^| findstr /V /B /C:" "
') do (
    rem // Reset flag:
    set "FLAG="
    rem // Check whether certain domain has been specified:
    if defined $DOMAIN (
        rem // Domain specified, so domain and owner must match:
        if /I "%%E"=="%$DOMAIN%\%$OWNER%" (
            rem // Match encountered, hence set flag:
            set "FLAG=#"
        )
    ) else (
        rem // Domain not specified, so owner must match only:
        set "OWN=%%E"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Dismiss domain of currently iterated file item:
        set "OWN=!OWN:*\=!"
        rem // Check whether owner matches:
        if "!OWN!"=="%$OWNER%" (
            endlocal
            rem // Match encountered, hence set flag:
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else endlocal
    )
    rem // Check whether flag is set:
    if defined FLAG (
        rem /* Flag is set, hence do something with current file item;
        rem    here, the file is moved to the given target directory;
        rem    remove the `if exist` query to force overwriting: */
        if not exist "%_TARGET%\%%~nxF" (
            > nul move /Y "%%~fF" "%_TARGET%\"
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

There are many explanatory remarks. The core command is `dir /Q`, which is capable of returning the owners of files. Note that it returns their login names preceded by the domain name and a backslash, like `DOMAIN\jdoe`, for example. Hence you need to specify the owner that way in the script. You may omit the domain prefix, in which case the domain is ignored. However, you cannot specify the display user name like `Jane Doe`, for instance, because this will not be recognised.

Note that the script will fail in case the given login name contains white-spaces.

Comment: Note that the initial [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40505600/1) does not work as ther was an error; [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40505600/2) works but does not move any files, it simply echoes them just for demonstration; [revision 3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40505600/3) finally moves the found files... I suggest to close/delete your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40516634) with the initial revision of this script...

Comment: Thank you very much for helping in the way that you are. I greatly appreciate it.
I closed out the other question.
I tried Revision 3 and it's now telling me "the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127738/discussion-between-drew-and-aschipfl).